# How to recursively get all fields in a unidirectional relationship?

Tags: relationship

I am trying to write a recursive method in java for getting all the fields in a unidirectional relationship. For example, I have one class A and it has number of fields and one of the field has a unidirectional relationship with class B. So I want the names of the fields of class A as well as of class B.

I am trying the below code but no success:

```
public class testReflection {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            C c = new C();
            Class klass = c.getClass();
            Field[] fields = getAllFields(klass);
            for (Field field : fields) {
                System.out.println(field.getName());
            }
        } catch (Throwable a_th) {
            a_th.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Field[] getAllFields(Class klass) {
        List<Field> fields = new ArrayList<Field>();
        fields.addAll(Arrays.asList(klass.getDeclaredFields()));
        if (klass.getSuperclass() != null) {
            fields.addAll(Arrays.asList(getAllFields(klass.getSuperclass())));
        }
        return fields.toArray(new Field[] {});
    }
}
```

How do I achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: No context, no programming language specified, no code given. I would say that your chances of getting any form of answer are slim.

Comment: i have added the required information...thanks!

Comment: can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Why not just use [`getType()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getType()) on the field and just process the field's class in the same way as you do with your containing class?

Comment: will it work?...As i want if field in class A has an association with class B then class B field also get listed.

Comment: Difficult to understand what you mean. Could you post a simple example of what your classes look like?

Comment: there are two classes A and B. In class A there are field like string name, int age, B b, relationship to class B and class B has fields like roll_no, etc. So i want to list the fields of both the classes. As field in class A find association with class B then field in class B also gets listed.

Comment: So, if you process the `B` exactly in the same way as `A`, you've got everything right?

Comment: yes..but how to achieve this? and if field in B and association with class C then fields of class C also gets listed. so i want to do it with recursion.

Comment: 1. Get field classes by calling `field.getType()`; 2. Filter out all fields that are not in your own packages to get rid of ints, Strings, etc.; 3. Process remaining field classes just like you processed `A`.

Comment: so what is wrong in above code?

Comment: What's wrong? You're not doing any of what I described above.

Comment: i don't want to filter out. i just want to list the all fields of classes rather its string or int.